# What is meant by "Each of two concentric discs has 20 radial sections of equal size"

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone show me a picture representation of the following question:

Each of two concentric discs has 20 radial sections of equal size. For each disc, 10 sections are painted red and 10 blue, in some arrangement. Prove that the two discs can be aligned so that at least 10 sections on the inner disc match colors with the corresponding sections on the outer disc.

I do not need a proof I just don't understand the question.

Comment: Discs are like a "pie diagram"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two discs, but there are only $6$ sectors with matching colours:

[image]

Here I've rotated the outer disc, and now $10$ sectors match.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks. I have no idea how I was supposed to put that together. Google did not help :)

Comment: Hint: after a random rotation, what is the expected number of matching sectors?

Answer (score 0):

You have two identical pizzas each with 20 equal-sized slices (knife cuts from the centre along a radius to the crust). Some slices don't have cheese. Find a way to put one pizza on top of the other with cuts aligned so that for at least 10 pairs of corresponding slices, either both have cheese or both don't.